# How can I cut all of these words to just one part?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have

```
{\"commentText\":\"\",\"srcLg\":\"/posts-01-1-2019828/15d5a290-4058-439c-a10b-51e5aa31bd2dlg.jpg\",\"srcSm\":\"/posts-01-1-2019828/15d5a290-4058-439c-a10b-51e5aa31bd2dsm.jpg\",\"useAsPrimary\":false}
```

I want to cut it to just

```
/posts-01-1-2019828/15d5a290-4058-439c-a10b-51e5aa31bd2dlg.jpg
```

Comment: You can get a better answer if you explain how you ended up with that string in the first place.

Comment: Can someone explain to me how this question is "too broad"? Maybe not researched or a duplicate sure, but it seems there is a pretty straightforward question being asked.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me. I may have to improve my communication because I don't speak English well.

Comment: find `.*?(?<="srcLg":")([^"]*).*` replace `\1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression might extract that:

```
[^ "]*lg\.jpg
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRWiFh/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Python has [an entire module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) dedicated to handling JSON data. For your use case:

```py
import json

data = json.loads(your_json_string)
print(data["srcLg"])
```

In addition to deserializing data, the module allows you to serialize data, pretty print JSON, and even do custom marshalling of data.